# Android ViewPager - Using a layout xml

Tags: android

I have a simple ViewPager example that just places a TextView with the current position. I want to adapt this to work in an existing app I have written.

My app currently uses a layout and then adjusts the values as needed. I want to use this layout with the ViewPager, but I currently am unable to get the layout.

When constructing my PagerAdapter I pass in the context from the main activity.

I am unable to use findViewById to get my layout though.

Can someone suggest the correct way to get it?

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position)
{
    LinearLayout info = (LinearLayout)((Activity)_context).findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(info, 0);

    return info;
}
```

The code above is from my PagerAdapter. I have a layout that I want to use as the pages for the pager, which I want to populate with info into the layouts TextViews and other views...

Comment: Found somewhere saying that casting the context to an activity will work - it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass a LayoutInflater to the adapter and then on the instantiateItem, I would create the View as I wished.

Even if it doesn't compile, could you post the code?

And btw have you check out [this implementation](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java)? It helped me once because I was forgetting the line

```
   ((ViewPager) collection).addView( some view...,0);
```

in the instantiateItem method.

Comment: That is the example I am building upon I think... certainly looked at it. I have that line too. Will look into your other suggestion...

Comment: I have done a few different implementations of PagerAdapter, if you posted the code, I could help in a much more efficiently way.

Comment: Ok, after seeing your code, i have some questions. DO you use setContentView on your Activity? Is R.id.linearlayout part of the view used on setContentView?

Comment: I would suggest that you move the layout you want to a seperate file called pager_layout.xml and use (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, null); where this mInflater is passed to the adapter instead of the context through getLayoutInflater().

Comment: The activity uses setContentView to load a layout that has the ViewPager in it. I have a second layout xml file (linearlayout.xml) which I want to use as a kind of template for the ViewPager - if that makes sense. Within the template layout is TextViews (among other views) that I would populate with the relevant information for that page.

Comment: so that is your problem. You can't use findViewByID. You need to use the inflater. have you tried that?

Comment: I'll look into inflater.... unless you can spare time to add an example here (PS: thanks for all the help!)

Comment: I've got it working using a LayoutInflater... so will accept your answer above! thanks!